# Set nginx module on off based on condition

Tags: linux, nginx, nginx-config

I have an nginx config for which I need to enable ssi on or off based on a condition.
I have tried moving ssi inside an if condition but nginx doesn't allow that.

```
location / {
     if(condition) {
          ssi on;
     }
}
```

I then tried setting on in a variable and use that

```
location / {
  set $ssi_flag off
  if(condition) {
      set $ssi_flag on
  }
  ssi $ssi_flag
}
```

For this nginx throws error ssi expects value on and off.
How can I set this.  A generic solution which can be used for other modules like ssi which expects on or off is very much appreciated.

Comment: Is that the complete `location /` block? If so, just place `ssi on;` inside the `if` block.

Comment: @RichardSmith In that case it will throw error ssi directive is not allowed here

Comment: Oh, that's not what [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html#ssi) says. Have you tried it?

Comment: @RichardSmith Yes I tried it, It says ssi is not allowed here.